# Will packing a struct ever misalign adjacent memory?

Tags: c, struct, padding

Consider the following struct

```
struct a{
    uint16_t foo1
    uint16_t foo2
    uint32_t foo3
    uint64_t foo4
    uint16_t foo5
    uint16_t foo6
}__attribute__(packed);
```

It's 20 bytes long. That's fine, as everything within the struct is aligned to word boundaries.

However, what happens if a well-meaning developer does the following:

```
static struct a foo;
static uint64_t b;
```

This would, theoretically, misalign b across a word boundary.

Interestingly, gcc seems to align `foo` to 16 bytes, however (if my knowledge of assembly is correct), it allows b to be misaligned:

```
.local  foo.2476
.comm   foo.2476,20,16
.local  b.2477
.comm   b.2477,8,8
```

Am I missing something here, or is this an example of the dangers of struct packing?

Comment: The start address of the struct is always aligned regardless of packing. Or at least most compilers behave like that.

Comment: I know that in an array, that would not be the case, `struct a foo[2]` would have misalignment. So what about `struct a foo1; struct a foo2;`, are you suggesting the compiler will add padding anyways?

Comment: Arrays is another story. A normal struct array will add padding at the end of each object. And the C standard states that array objects must be allocated adjacently. So if you remove trailing padding, the compiler has no choice but to allocate the next struct item misaligned.

Comment: Who says that `b` is misaligned if it starts at a 4-byte boundary?  Alignment requirements are architecture-specific, and the alignment requirement for a multibyte type can be smaller than that type's size.

Comment: Where do you want to put that code? Into another packed structure? In a non-packed structure? As separate variables at file scope?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Architecture-agnostically, wouldn't alignment requirements be equal to the size?

Comment: @Gerhardh  I don't know, it's part of framework code and the struct itself could be allocated pretty much anywhere (indirectly) by a user.

Comment: Unless you put it into another packed struct, what should prevent the compiler from adding required padding between the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, what happens if a well-meaning developer does the following:
>
> ```
> static struct a foo;
> static uint64_t b;
> ```
>
> This would, theoretically, misalign b across a word boundary.

No, there's no particular reason for `b` to be misaligned in that case, not any more than if you instead had

```
static char foo;
static uint64_t b;
```

.  Supposing that `uint64_t` has an alignment requirement greater than 1, a poor-quality compiler *could* misalign `b` in that case, but in practice, you're unlikely ever to see such a result.  Compilers lay out storage for variables at their discretion, and normally at well-aligned addresses.

> Interestingly, gcc seems to align foo to 16 bytes, however (if my knowledge of assembly is correct), it allows b to be misaligned:
>   [...]
>
> Am I missing something here, or is this an example of the dangers of struct packing?

You are almost certainly missing something.  I'd bet dollars to donuts that your machine's `uint64_t` has a 4-byte, not 8-byte, alignment requirement.

Comment: More to the point a compiler miss-aligning such things would be kaput considering the standard.

Comment: Not necessarily, @Swordfish.  On an architecture where (hardware-)misaligned access can be performed successfully, an implementation could randomly or even systematically misalign variables in the hardware sense, yet still fully conform to the standard.

Comment: I meant misalign considering aligning requirements of the standard.

Comment: I understand what you meant, @Swordfish, but the Standard allows implementations to choose types' C-level alignment requirements for themselves.  There is therefore very little sense in which an implementation can fail to satisfy the Standard's requirements for object alignment.  In fact, I think there is *none* at the language level (ignoring the standard library), apart from consistency with `_Alignof` and adherence to `_Alignas`.